# Regular Expression [^)] Cannot Match A Double Quote

Tags: regex, gnu, grep

I am using GNU grep on Windows 7 command prompt.

I have a file **jsutfstr.txt** whose content is like this:

```
some lines
HELLO("abc",adf)
HELLO("def", sd)
some lines
some lines
some lines
```

And I want to grep the **HELLO**(..) pattern.  In the windows command prompt I used these:

```
C:\bin>Egrep     HELLO\(\"[^)]+\) jsutfstr.txt
HELLO("abc",adf)
HELLO("def", sd)

C:\bin>Egrep     HELLO\([^)]+\) jsutfstr.txt
```

So, the second pattern yields nothing.  I don't understand why I have to specify \" explicitly.  Isn't that the [^)] matches everything not equal to **)** including a double quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you run in to the shell parsing the line first and `^` is the escape character for `cmd`. So the line that gets passed to `grep` in the second case is

```
Egrep     HELLO\([)]+\) jsutfstr.txt
```

while in the first case the `"` starts a quoted argument where `cmd` will not look into.

You can just quote the complete argument to avoid that:

```
Egrep "HELLO\([^)]+\)" jsutfstr.txt
```

Comment: Thx, that is very helpful. Windows command prompt really troublesome. So what should I use in the command prompt to achieve the desired result?